# AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'Marker'

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, folium

I have the following code:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

map1 = folium.Map(location=SF_COORDINATES, zoom_start=12)
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(map1) 

for each in data[0:MAX_RECORDS].iterrows():
    map1.Marker(location = [each[1]['Y'],each[1]['X']], 
    clustered_marker = True).add_to(marker_cluster)

display(map1)
```

And I get this error message:

`AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'Marker'`

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Marker` is part of `folium`, not of `folium.Map`.

See the [folium Getting Started](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers).